# Set default GPU for switchable ATI/Intel graphics

Tags: 12.10, drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx

I am running `Quantal` using the `Catalyst 13.3` ATI driver for `Intel HD 4000/ATI HD 7670M` setup. I can switch between integrated and dedicated GPU with `amdconfig --px-igpu` or `amdconfig --px-dgpu`. Upon reboot it's always the dedicated card that is selected, so I have to switch manually again after boot and then restart `X`. Is there a way to set the integrated GPU to be default? This way I can switch to dedicated graphics when needed (not very often).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps try and enter the command `amdconfig --px-igpu` in this file: `/etc/rc.local`